# Ora 00907 missing right parenthesis in SQL

Tags: sql, oracle, datetime, subquery, greatest-n-per-group

```
SELECT
    g.msisdn, c.name3, c.id_number,
    decode(g.sub_state, 'B01', 'Active', 'B02', 'Close', 'B03', 'Suspend','B02', 'Barring') STATUS,
    decode(g.prepaid_flag, '0', 'Prepaid', '1', 'Postpaid','3', 'Hybrid') RATING,
    d.offer_name, t.create_date
    FROM inf_subscriber_all g
    INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.sub_id, a.cust_id, a.offer_id, a.create_date FROM (
    SELECT cust_id,MAX(create_date) AS maxdate FROM his_offers WHERE primary_flag ='1' GROUP BY cust_id) as tm 
    INNER JOIN his_offers a ON a.create_date = tm.maxdate and a.cust_id = tm.cust_id) as a ON a.cust_id = g.cust_id
    INNER JOIN inf_customer_all c ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
    INNER JOIN pdm_offer d ON d.offer_id = a.offer_id
    WHERE g.msisdn IN ('135018013','197745505','195154724')
```

Please help, i dont know why i am getting missing right parenthesis error for this sql script

Comment: (1) You tagged your question MuSQL(i), but the error message indicates Oracle. Which database are you actually using? (2) Please explain the purpose of this query - it is not self-explanatory.

Comment: Because you need to close the parentheses coming after first `INNER JOIN`, and add a join condition `ON ... = ....` at the end of the query.

Comment: You are missing a closing parantheses. There are 2 opening parantheses after the INNER JOIN, but only one closing parantheses.

Comment: The parens are balanced, it's the AS keyword which is not supported by Oracle

Comment: Thank you guys for your insight, this query is to find the latest information of the subscriber. I had removed the AS keyword, however it don't give result as expected, the query showed the history of subscriber.  i wish to have the latest record of subscriber

Comment: @Dnoeth - where do you find the AS keyword not supported by oracle?  Check the SQL Language Reference, under the SELECT statement, under the explanation of 'select list'.   "AS" is an optional (though completely superfluous) part of the assignment of a column or expression alias.

Comment: @EdStevens Of course, Oracle supports **column** aliases using AS, but not **table** aliases using AS.

Answer (score 3):

You tagged your question MySQL but the error message indicates Oracle, as does the syntax (`DECODE()` is supported in Oracle but not in MySQL).

The parentheses in your query do balance. An issue that catches the eye is you are using the `as` keyword to alias the subqueries. Oracle does not support that (`as` is allowed for column alias only); you would need to remove these:

```
SELECT ...
FROM inf_subscriber_all g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT ...
    FROM (
        ...
    ) as tm                         ---> here
    INNER JOIN his_offers a ON ...
) as a ON ...                       ---> and here
INNER JOIN inf_customer_all c ON ...
INNER JOIN pdm_offer d ON ...
WHERE ...
```

As for the query itself: it seems the subquery is meant to select the `his_offer` row that has the greatest `create_date` for each `cust_id`. This might be more efficiently expressed with window functions:

```
SELECT
    g.msisdn, c.name3, c.id_number,
    decode(g.sub_state, 'B01', 'Active', 'B02', 'Close', 'B03', 'Suspend','B02', 'Barring') STATUS,
    decode(g.prepaid_flag, '0', 'Prepaid', '1', 'Postpaid','3', 'Hybrid') RATING,
    d.offer_name, t.create_date
FROM inf_subscriber_all g
INNER JOIN (
    SELECT a.*, RANK() OVER(PARTIION BY cust_id ORDER BY create_date) rn
    FROM his_offers
) as a ON a.cust_id = g.cust_id AND a.rn = 1
INNER JOIN inf_customer_all c ON c.cust_id = a.cust_id
INNER JOIN pdm_offer d ON d.offer_id = a.offer_id
WHERE g.msisdn IN ('135018013','197745505','195154724')
```

Comment: Thank you, GMB, Sorry, i forgot that this error message is meant for oracle, aside i have tried the given function. The 'missing the right parenthesis' error still prompted. the query is get lastest subscriber information